# Appending icon to the end of the column of the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a situation where i have `six columns getting generated dynamically` in the row.

```
<div class ="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
      <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add an icon to the end of the `row`, but it breaks down because there are `six columns` as the icon is 7th one. Is there anyway we can `add/append` the icon to the end of the row without breaking it into next row.

Comment: Can you add the CSS style to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using absolute positioning for icon. You need to do some setup before that by adding position relative to the row it contains.

HTML below.

```
<div class="container">
<div class ="row columns-parent">
  <div class="col-sm-2 columns">1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 columns">2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 columns">3
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 columns">4
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 columns">5
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 columns">6 
  </div>
  <div class="icon">icon here </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.icon{
    position : absolute;
    right : 0;
}

.columns-parent{
    position:relative;
    padding-right:60px;

}
```

Set the right and top as per your requirements. Also adjust the padding right of the row(60 px here) depending on number of pixels your icon is gonna take so that icon doesnt overlap the content.

JS Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/YJcLS/1/